# The sum of reciprocal squares: estimating the remainder

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ denote the $n$th remainder of the series 
$$
1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\ldots
$$
In other words, 
$$
a_n = \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\left(1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\ldots +\frac{1}{n^2}\right).
$$
I noticed that for small $n$ the following is true 
$$
\frac{1}{n+1}<a_n<\frac{1}{n}\tag{$*$}
$$
and tried to prove it for all $n$. Using induction on $n$, I ended up having to prove the estimates
$$\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot \frac{n^2+3n+3}{(n+1)(n+2)}<a_n<\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}$$
which are even stronger than $(*)$.

My question is whether $(*)$ is true for all $n$ and, if so, how could one prove it?

Comment: For the asymptotic of the remainder term, try Euler-Maclaurin formula.

Comment: Here is a discussion by several MSE users of this problem: [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685435/trying-to-get-a-bound-on-the-tail-of-the-series-for-zeta2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to show $(*)$ is to note that for $k>1$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}< \frac{1}{k^2}<\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}
$$
then add these inequalities starting from $k=n+1$, using the telescoping aspect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be true from computing large $a_i$'s by Mathematica but induction does not work here. However, induction does work on the bounds $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < a_n < \frac{1}{n^2}$.