# Simple equivalent of the rest of the series $\sum\limits_n\frac1{n^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Consider the converging series
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n\geqslant1}{\frac{1}{n^3}}
\end{equation}
I want to find an equivalent of the rest :
\begin{equation}
R_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^3}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Define "equivalent".

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition

Comment: $R_n\sim 1/2n^2$.

Comment: The technique from this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685435/) is easily adapted to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Summing the inequalities $$\frac1{k^2}-\frac1{(k+1)^2}\leqslant\frac2{k^3}\leqslant\frac1{(k-1)^2}-\frac1{k^2}$$ yields $$\frac1{2(n+1)^2}\leqslant R_n\leqslant\frac1{2n^2}.$$ From here, one sees that the RHS is a simple equivalent of $R_n$ when $n\to\infty$.

More generally, for every $\alpha\gt0$, $$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^{1+\alpha}}\sim\int_n^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^{1+\alpha}}=\frac1{\alpha n^\alpha},$$ where the equivalent sign means that the ratio of the two sides of the sign converges to $1$. "Hard" inequalities, similar to the ones above and using only the fact that the function $x\mapsto 1/x^{1+\alpha}$ is nonincreasing and is a multiple of the derivative of $x\mapsto 1/x^{\alpha}$, are $$\frac1{\alpha (n+1)^\alpha}=\int_{n+1}^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^{1+\alpha}}\leqslant\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^{1+\alpha}}\leqslant\int_n^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^{1+\alpha}}=\frac1{\alpha n^\alpha}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the theorem: if $x_n \sim y_n > 0$ and $\sum x_n < \infty$ then
$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty x_n \sim \sum_{n=N}^\infty y_n
$$

---

Let $$u_n= \frac1{2n^2}$$

Then check that $u_n - u_{n+1}\sim \frac1{n^3}$
(you can find such a relation looking for a $u_n$ in the form $u_n = \frac a{x_m}$).

Hence
$$
\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac 1{n^3}\sim  u_N = \frac 1{2N^2} 
$$